# How to extract JSON into a table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a database filled with json document, one per row, like this:

```
[{
    "ID": "TOT",
    "type": "ABS",
    "value": "32.0"
},
{
    "ID": "T1",
    "type": "ABS",
    "value": "9.0"
},
{
    "ID": "T2",
    "type": "ABS",
    "value": "8.0"
},
{
    "ID": "T3",
    "type": "ABS",
    "value": "15.0"
}]
```

I need to extract these information in order to insert data into a table like this:

```
     pod          T1    T2    T3    TOT
IT001E18486545    9.0   8.0  15.0   32.0
```

I tried with the following:

```
select pod, json_array_elements(jsond::json) ->>'value' as value, 
json_array_elements(jsond::json) ->>'ID' as ID,  
json_array_elements(jsond::json) ->>'type' as stype
from tst_json
```

but this way I have a result like this

[image: this]

which is not what I need.

Comment: Are the entries always in the same order in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pivot the data using the `case ... then ... end` construct:

```
select 
    pod, 
    case when value->>'ID' = 'T1' then value->>'value' end as "T1",
    case when value->>'ID' = 'T2' then value->>'value' end as "T2",
    case when value->>'ID' = 'T3' then value->>'value' end as "T3",
    case when value->>'ID' = 'TOT' then value->>'value' end as "TOT"
from tst_json
cross join json_array_elements(jsond)

      pod       | T1  | T2  |  T3  | TOT  
----------------+-----+-----+------+------
 IT001E18486545 |     |     |      | 32.0
 IT001E18486545 | 9.0 |     |      | 
 IT001E18486545 |     | 8.0 |      | 
 IT001E18486545 |     |     | 15.0 | 
(4 rows)
```

Use `max()` and `group by` to get a single row for each `pod` and get rid of nulls:

```
select 
    pod, 
    max(case when value->>'ID' = 'T1' then value->>'value' end) as "T1",
    max(case when value->>'ID' = 'T2' then value->>'value' end) as "T2",
    max(case when value->>'ID' = 'T3' then value->>'value' end) as "T3",
    max(case when value->>'ID' = 'TOT' then value->>'value' end) as "TOT"
from tst_json
cross join json_array_elements(jsond)
group by pod

      pod       | T1  | T2  |  T3  | TOT  
----------------+-----+-----+------+------
 IT001E18486545 | 9.0 | 8.0 | 15.0 | 32.0
(1 row)
```